# How to upload file on server by phoenix

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I am trying to upload image file to server by phoenix.
I had not found any good examples for it.

Following code is one I made, but it not works.
I have following errors.

```
no function clause matching in FileUploadWeb.PageController.upload/2
```

**controller**

```
defmodule FileUploadWeb.PageController do
  use FileUploadWeb, :controller

  def index(conn, _params) do
    render(conn, "index.html")
  end

  def upload(conn, %{"upload" => upload}) do
    path_upload = upload["photo"]
    File.cp(path_upload.path, Path.absname("upload/#{path_upload.filename}}"))
    render(conn, "index.html")
  end
end
```

**index.html.eex**

```
<div>
<%= form_for @conn, "/upload", [multipart: true], fn f ->%>
    <%= file_input f, :photo, class: "form-control" %>
    <%= submit "Upload", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
</div>
```

**router**

```
  scope "/", FileUploadWeb do
    pipe_through :browser

    get "/", PageController, :index
    post "/upload", PageController, :upload
  end
```

Would you give me good example for it?
Thanks.

Comment: It seems as though there is no `"upload"` key in the params received by `upload/2`. Have you tried maybe inspecting the params to see what the key should be?

Answer (score -1):

This is a link of how to do file upload from the phoenix docs: https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/1.3.0-rc.1/file_uploads.html

Comment: Even despite the link might contain some helpful info, this answer is not welcome on stack overflow. Please read [Provide context for links](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) section.